# Can I bind a ReactiveCommand to MouseDown event on Textbox?

Tags: wpf, textbox, reactiveui

I'm trying to get the WPF ReactiveUI framework's new view ctor binding to bind a ReactiveCommand that is working on a Button click to wire up to a TextBox MouseDown/click event. The following doesn't work.

```
public partial class KeypadNumberView 
    : IKeypadNumberView
    , IViewFor<IOnScreenKeyboard>
{
    public KeypadNumberView()
    {
        ViewModel = new KeyboardViewModel();

        InitializeComponent();

        this.Bind(ViewModel, x => x.EnteredText);
        this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.Delete, v => v.EnteredText, "MouseDown" ); // doesn't work
        this.BindCommand(ViewModel, vm => vm.Delete); // <== works
```

Comment: I'm a knucklehead or I just didn't understand TextBox and MouseDown. This was fixed, by setting Focusable="False" on the TextBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That seems like it should work. Can you file a bug at http://github.com/reactiveui/reactiveui ?

Comment: All fixed, see comment above. Thanks!